# Segmentation fault when sorting an array of strings when using strcpy in c code

Tags: c, string, sorting, crash, strcpy

Im trying to sort an array of string.If i remove the line

```
strcpy(a[j-1],a[j]);
```

terminal doesn't crash.

The array of strings is allocated this way in case that s the problem

```
array=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*N);

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        array[i]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
```

Sort function

```
void bubblesort1(char **a,int K)
{
    int i,j;
    char temp[6];

    for(i=1; i<K; i++)
        for(j=(K-1); j>=i; j--)
        {
            if(strcmp(a[j],a[j-1])>0)
            {
                strcpy(temp,a[j-1]);
                strcpy(a[j-1],a[j]);
                strcpy(a[j],temp);

            }

        }

}
```

Why am i getting the crash?

Comment: are you sure none of the strings has length `>5`?

Comment: If a string has 6 characters like "dancer" then you need 7 bytes, as a byte is need to hold the null (0) terminator.

Comment: that seems to be the case...thanks

Comment: With your data layout, you don't need to copy the contents of the string around with `strcpy`; it is enough to swap the pointers to char.

Comment: How do you read data into what `a`'s elements refer to?

Comment: im actually trying to make an array of string with random numbers from 100000 to 999999...i m using  for(i=0; i<K; i++)
  sprintf(array[i],"%d",(rand()%999999+100000));          i tried swapping the pointers instead of strcpy and it worked though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you allow an extra byte for the null terminator whenever working with character strings.